# Smoke alarm positioning - dead air?

Tags: smoke-detectors

For aesthetics, I'd ideally like to place the smoke alarm in this room in the middle of this 'square' area - see dot in attached picture.

[image: Image of ceiling with dot marking the centre of a square area made by walls and a built-in cupboard]

It's more than 300mm from any ceiling/wall corner, and thus meets code where I live (QLD Australia). However I wonder if that area might create some dead air and delay alarm activation, and if I should move it ~300-400mm further in towards the centre of the room.

Am I overthinking this or is that a valid concern?

[Smoke alarm info sheet for my state](https://www.qfes.qld.gov.au/sites/default/files/2021-05/SmokeAlarmInstallationInformationSheet.pdf)

Comment: Smoke rises and fills the room from top down. It isn't going to follow regular ventilation flows. If anything, it'll detect smoke from the doorway faster, and smoke inside the room will go up anyways.

Comment: @Nelson The doorway comment makes it a good answer. To my understanding, near the door is the preferred placement, as far as bedrooms are concerned.

Comment: @Jack I'm not saying it should be moved to the centre of the room, just wondering if it needs moving maybe 40cm in. Will update to clarify.

Comment: @Nelson - make an answer out of that!